# Проверка подставления значений из связанной таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql

Добрый вечер.
У меня есть таблицы Voprosi[Id,Vopros],VariantiOtvetov[Id,IdVoprosa,Variant,IsTrue], Uspevaemost[IdUser,IdVoprosa,IdVarianta]
Например, вопрос №333 имеет варианты ответов с id 1000, 1001, 1002.
Как настроить проверку в таблице Uspevaemost, чтоб если выбран id вопроса 333, то в поле id варианта можно было подставить только эти значения, а не все другие?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Заведите таблицу с допустимыми вариантами ответов на вопросы. Добавьте внешний ключ, ведущий в эту таблицу.

Впрочем, такая таблица у вас уже есть, просто добавьте внешний ключ.

Answer (score 0):

В MSSQL это можно сделать с помощью ограничения CHECK для таблицы.

В MySQL такие ограничения не поддерживались, если ничего не изменилось за последнее время.